# Accessing and changing a static variable from another compilation unit using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, static

If I have a static variable `my_var` in the first.c file and pointer ptr_my_var which points to this variable, is it normal to access and change the variable `my_var` using the `ptr_my_var` pointer from another compilation unit?

```
// first.c
...
static float my_var;
float *ptr_my_var = &my_var;
...

// second.c 
...
extern float *ptr_my_varl;

void bar() {
  (*ptr_my_varl) = 777.777;
}

// third.c
extern float *ptr_my_varl;

void foo() {
  (*ptr_my_varl) = 1.233;
}
```

Comment: Why not doing a simple global variable ?

Comment: It's well-defined. Whether it's "normal" or "good style" depends on the context, and probably also how you're asking.

Comment: @larsmans I cannot think of any case for any kind of application, ranging from mission-critical real-time embedded to Windows desktop apps, where this would ever be good style or even justified.

Comment: @Lundin It's not pretty, I won't recommend it, but sometimes you have to jump through hoops. (Think DLLs, legacy code.)

Comment: @larsmans If end up in a situation where you _must_ use bad programming practice, it means you have even bigger problems elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is widely recognized as very bad programming practice *).

The whole purpose with declaring the variable as static is that you want to reduce the scope of the variable, making it private to the module it exists in. This is the C way of achieving [*private encapsulation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), one of the corner stones of object-oriented program design.

---

*) See for example [CERT C DCL15-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL15-C.+Declare+file-scope+objects+or+functions+that+do+not+need+external+linkage+as+static) or MISRA-C:2012 rule 8.8.

Comment: The CERT rule is unrelated. The MISRA standard is not open, so I cannot read it. Also, I can imagine a situation where e.g. initialization code for the variable (or lookup table) is outside the compilation unit in which it's defined - then passing a pointer to it is the only way to make it work.

Comment: @anatolyg It is not unrelated. Read it. "Risk Assessment. Allowing too many objects to have external linkage can use up descriptive identifiers, leading to more complicated identifiers, violations of abstraction models, and possible name conflicts with libraries. If the compilation unit implements a data abstraction, it may also expose invocations of private functions from outside the abstraction."

Comment: @anatolyg With **good program design**, the initialization code is **always** in the same module (file) as the variable. With **bad** program design, anything is indeed possible.

Comment: Also in addition to the mentioned coding standards, there's also multi-threading issues whenever you use variables with static storage duration. All code handling the thread-safe accessing to the private variable needs to be in the same module as the variable, or you are creating a spaghetti code hell.